# Android Date Picker Formatting

Tags: android

I am trying to get date in this format "Friday 12 October 2011" from the DateTimePicker Class below. I am new to date time picker and found this code online. When i modify it i get the following output "17 apr. 2013 15:44:33" but i want to get "Tuesday 17 apr. 2013". Here is the Date Picker class

```
public class DateTimePicker implements OnClickListener
{
    private DatePicker datePicker;
    private TimePicker timePicker;
    private ViewSwitcher viewSwitcher;

    private final int SET_DATE=100,SET_TIME=101,SET=102,CANCEL=103;

    private Button btn_setDate,btn_setTime,btn_set,btn_cancel; 

    private Calendar calendar_date=null;

    private Activity activity;

    private ICustomDateTimeListener iCustomDateTimeListener = null;

    private Dialog dialog;

    private boolean is24HourView = true;

    public DateTimePicker(Activity a,ICustomDateTimeListener customDateTimeListener) 
    {
        activity = a;
        iCustomDateTimeListener = customDateTimeListener;

        dialog = new Dialog(activity);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        View dialogView = getDateTimePickerLayout();
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
    }

    public View getDateTimePickerLayout()
    {
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_match_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams linear_wrap_wrap = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams  frame_match_wrap = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(FrameLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, FrameLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

        LinearLayout.LayoutParams button_params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,1.0f);

        LinearLayout linear_main = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_main.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);
        linear_main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        linear_main.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        LinearLayout linear_child = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_child.setLayoutParams(linear_wrap_wrap);
        linear_child.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);

        LinearLayout linear_top = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_top.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_setDate = new Button(activity);
        btn_setDate.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setDate.setText("Set Date");
        btn_setDate.setId(SET_DATE);
        btn_setDate.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_setDate.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        //55
        btn_setTime = new Button(activity);
        btn_setTime.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_setTime.setText("Set Time");
        btn_setTime.setId(SET_TIME);
        btn_setTime.setOnClickListener(this);
        btn_setTime.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        linear_top.addView(btn_setDate);
        linear_top.addView(btn_setTime);

        viewSwitcher = new ViewSwitcher(activity);
        viewSwitcher.setLayoutParams(frame_match_wrap);

        datePicker = new DatePicker(activity);
        timePicker = new TimePicker(activity);

        viewSwitcher.addView(timePicker);
        viewSwitcher.addView(datePicker);

        LinearLayout linear_bottom = new LinearLayout(activity);
        linear_match_wrap.topMargin = 8;
        linear_bottom.setLayoutParams(linear_match_wrap);

        btn_set = new Button(activity);
        btn_set.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_set.setText("Set");
        btn_set.setId(SET);
        btn_set.setOnClickListener(this);

        btn_cancel = new Button(activity);
        btn_cancel.setLayoutParams(button_params);
        btn_cancel.setText("Cancel");
        btn_cancel.setId(CANCEL);
        btn_cancel.setOnClickListener(this);

        linear_bottom.addView(btn_set);
        linear_bottom.addView(btn_cancel);

        linear_child.addView(linear_top);
        linear_child.addView(viewSwitcher);
        linear_child.addView(linear_bottom);

        linear_main.addView(linear_child);

        return linear_main;
    }

    public void showDialog()
    {
        if(!dialog.isShowing())
         {
            if(calendar_date==null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            timePicker.setIs24HourView(is24HourView);
            timePicker.setCurrentHour(calendar_date.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
            timePicker.setCurrentMinute(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MINUTE));

            datePicker.updateDate(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date.get(Calendar.DATE));

            dialog.show();

            btn_setDate.performClick();
         }
    }

    public void dismissDialog()
    {
        if(!dialog.isShowing())
         dialog.dismiss();  
    }

    public void setDate(Calendar calendar)
    {
        if(calendar!=null)
        calendar_date = calendar;   
    }

    public void setDate(Date date)
    {
        if(date!=null)
        {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.setTime(date);    
        }
    }

    public void setDate(int year,int month,int day)
    {
        if( month<12 && month>=0 && day<32 && day>=0 && year>100 && year<3000)
        {
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar_date.set(year, month, day);
        }

    }
    public void setTimeIn24HourFormat(int hourIn24Format,int minute)
    {
        if(hourIn24Format<24 && hourIn24Format>=0 && minute>=0 && minute<60)
        {
            if(calendar_date==null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),hourIn24Format, minute);

            is24HourView = true;
        }
    }

    public void setTimeIn12HourFormat(int hourIn12Format,int minute,boolean isAM)
    {
        if(hourIn12Format<13 && hourIn12Format>0 && minute>=0 && minute<60)
        {
            if(hourIn12Format==12)
                 hourIn12Format = 0;

            int hourIn24Format = hourIn12Format;

            if(!isAM)
            hourIn24Format += 12;

            if(calendar_date==null)
            calendar_date = Calendar.getInstance();

            calendar_date.set(calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR),calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),hourIn24Format,minute);

            is24HourView = false;
        }
    }

    public void set24HourFormat(boolean is24HourFormat)
    {
        is24HourView = is24HourFormat;
    }

    public interface ICustomDateTimeListener 
    {
        public void onSet(Calendar calendarSelected,Date dateSelected,int year,String monthFullName,String monthShortName,int monthNumber,int date,String weekDayFullName,String weekDayShortName);
        public void onCancel();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        switch (v.getId()) 
        {
         case SET_DATE: btn_setTime.setEnabled(true);
                        btn_setDate.setEnabled(false);
                        viewSwitcher.showNext();
                        break;

        /* case SET_TIME: btn_setTime.setEnabled(false);
                        btn_setDate.setEnabled(true);
                        viewSwitcher.showPrevious();
                        break;
            */
         case SET:      if(dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if(iCustomDateTimeListener!=null)
                        {
                            int month = datePicker.getMonth();
                            int year  = datePicker.getYear();
                            int day  = datePicker.getDayOfMonth();

                            calendar_date.set(year, month, day);

                            iCustomDateTimeListener.onSet(calendar_date, calendar_date.getTime(), calendar_date.get(Calendar.YEAR), getMonthFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)), getMonthShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH)),calendar_date.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH),getWeekDayFullName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)),getWeekDayShortName(calendar_date.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK)));
                        }
                       // resetData();
                        break;

         case CANCEL:   if(dialog.isShowing())
                        dialog.dismiss();
                        if(iCustomDateTimeListener!=null)
                        iCustomDateTimeListener.onCancel(); 
                        resetData();
                        break;
        }
    }


    /**
     * @param date date in String 
     * @param fromFormat format of your <b>date</b> eg: if your date is 2011-07-07 09:09:09 then your format will be <b>yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss</b> 
     * @param toFormat format to which you want to convert your <b>date</b> eg: if required format is 31 July 2011 then the toFormat should be <b>d MMMM yyyy</b> 
     * @return formatted date
     */
    public static String convertDate(String date,String fromFormat,String toFormat)
    {
        String formattedDate="";
        try 
        {
            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(fromFormat);
            Date d = simpleDateFormat.parse(date);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(d);

            simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(toFormat);
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            formattedDate = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            if(e!=null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return formattedDate;
    }

    /**
     * @param monthNumber Month Number starts with 0. For <b>January</b> it is <b>0</b> and for <b>December</b> it is <b>11</b>.
     * @return
     */
    private String getMonthFullName(int monthNumber) 
    {
        String monthName="";

        if(monthNumber>=0 && monthNumber<12)
        try 
        {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            if(e!=null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return monthName;
    }

    /**
     * @param monthNumber Month Number starts with 0. For <b>January</b> it is <b>0</b> and for <b>December</b> it is <b>11</b>.
     * @return
     */
    private String getMonthShortName(int monthNumber) 
    {
        String monthName="";

        if(monthNumber>=0 && monthNumber<12)
        try 
        {
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthNumber);

        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM");
        simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
        monthName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
             if(e!=null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return monthName;
    }

    /**
     * @param weekDayNumber Week Number starts with 1. For <b>Sunday</b> it is <b>1</b> and for <b>Saturday</b> it is <b>7</b>.
     * @return
     */
    private String getWeekDayFullName(int weekDayNumber) 
    {
        String weekName = "";

        if(weekDayNumber>0 && weekDayNumber<8)
        {
        try {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            if(e!=null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return weekName;
    }

    /**
     * @param weekDayNumber Week Number starts with 1. For <b>Sunday</b> it is <b>1</b> and for <b>Saturday</b> it is <b>7</b>.
     * @return
     */
    private String getWeekDayShortName(int weekDayNumber) 
    {
        String weekName = "";
        if(weekDayNumber>0 && weekDayNumber<8)
        {
        try {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, weekDayNumber);

            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EE");
            simpleDateFormat.setCalendar(calendar);
            weekName = simpleDateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            if(e!=null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        }
        return weekName;
    }

    private int getHourIn12Format(int hour24) 
    {
        int  hourIn12Format = 0;

        if(hour24==0)
        hourIn12Format = 12;
        else if(hour24<=12)
        hourIn12Format = hour24;
        else
        hourIn12Format = hour24-12; 

        return hourIn12Format;
    }

    private String getAMPM(Calendar calendar) 
    {
        String ampm = (calendar.get(Calendar.AM_PM)==(Calendar.AM))? "AM":"PM";
        return ampm;
    }

    private void resetData()
    {
        calendar_date = null;
        is24HourView = true;
    }

    public static String pad(int i)
    {
        return i<=9?"0"+i:""+i;
    }

    public static String getSecondsFromMillis(long milliseconds) {
        return "" + ((int) ((milliseconds / 1000) % 60));
    }

    public static String getMinutesFromMillis(long milliseconds) {
        return "" + (int) ((milliseconds / (1000 * 60)) % 60);
    }

    public static String getHoursFromMillis(long milliseconds) {
        return "" + (int) ((milliseconds / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
    }

    /**
     * @param monthNumber Month Number starts with 0. For <b>January</b> it is <b>0</b> and for <b>December</b> it is <b>11</b>.
     * @param year 
     * @return
     */
    public static int getDaysInMonth(int monthNumber,int year)
    {
          int days=0;
          if(monthNumber>=0 && monthNumber<12){
          try 
        {
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
              int date = 1;
              calendar.set(year, monthNumber, date);
              days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
        } catch (Exception e) 
        {
            if(e!=null)
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
          }
          return days;
    }

    /**
     * @param monthNumber Month Number starts with 0. For <b>January</b> it is <b>0</b> and for <b>December</b> it is <b>11</b>.
     * @return
     */
    public static int getDaysInMonthInPresentYear(int monthNumber)
    {
           int days=0;
           if(monthNumber>=0 && monthNumber<12){
           try 
            {
                Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                  int date = 1;
                  int year = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR); 
                  calendar.set(year, monthNumber, date);
                  days = calendar.getActualMaximum(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
            } catch (Exception e) 
            {
                if(e!=null)
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           }
              return days;
    }

    public static int getDaysDifference(Date fromDate,Date toDate)
    {
         if(fromDate==null||toDate==null)
             return 0;

         return (int)( (toDate.getTime() - fromDate.getTime()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

    public static int getDaysDifference(Calendar calendar1,Calendar calendar2)
    {
         if(calendar1==null||calendar2==null)
             return 0;

         return (int)( (calendar2.getTimeInMillis() - calendar1.getTimeInMillis()) / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    }

}
```

I am calling it in my MainActivity.Class as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ICustomDateTimeListener 
{
    private TextView textView;
    private DateTimePicker dateTimePicker;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview);

        dateTimePicker = new DateTimePicker(MainActivity.this, this);
        dateTimePicker.set24HourFormat(true);
        dateTimePicker.showDialog();
    //rrr
    }

    @Override
    public void onSet(Calendar calendarSelected, Date dateSelected, int year,
            String monthFullName, String monthShortName, int monthNumber,
            int date, String weekDayFullName, String weekDayShortName) 
     {
        textView.setText(dateSelected.toLocaleString());
     }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() 
    {
        Log.d("datetimepickerdialog", "canceled");
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must do this in onSet method of your activity:

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE dd MMM yyyy");
textView.setText(formatter.format(dateSelected));
```

Comment: nice :) now i need to make the first letter capital :)) thanks you ararog